# Getting data after the page loads works inconsistently

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, page-load-time, text-size

I'm attempting to make a menu that resizes to fit each device size.  I have the buttons scaled, and the text will now correctly autofit into the buttons, but some text is longer than others.  To accommodate this, I attempted to get the textSize of the largest text item and set the other text sizes to it with:

```
private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        about.setTextSize(contact.getEndTextSize());
        hours.setTextSize(contact.getEndTextSize());
        shop.setTextSize(contact.getEndTextSize());
    }
}
```

The issue is that this will only work part of the time.  I can navigate to one page multiple times and it will either work or won't.

My understanding is that onPostExecute is called when the background computation has finished.  Is the issue that this timing doesn't necessarily coincide with when the page finishes rendering?  Is there a better way to approach getting the textSize?

Comment: is the button generated on runtime or it's there all the time?

Comment: It's there all the time.